# Search for one or more characters and replace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

By using `indexOf()` I was able to detect if the input contains "SP-" and replace.

However, I need to look for more than one set of characters:
`sp-`, `SP-`, `eb-`, `EB-` and more...

I have the following to replace `sp-` and `SP-` but I don't want to replicate this entire block for every instance.

```
// Check for 'sp-' characters in the order ID.
if (order_id.indexOf("SP-") !== -1) {
  // Remove string from input
  form.find('input[name="orderid"]').val(order_id.replace("SP-", ""));
}

// Check for 'SP-' characters in the order ID.
if (order_id.indexOf("sp-") !== -1) {
  // Remove string from input
  form.find('input[name="orderid"]').val(order_id.replace("sp-", ""));
}
```

*Update* - Just thought of a better solution, find all characters before and including `-` and remove it. So we're not limited to a specific list in case new prefixes are added at a later date.

`sp-1234`, `SP-1234`, `xx-1234`, etc.

Comment: Create a function, and call that in a loop?

Comment: Updating a question to basically a new question when there are answers is typically a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace all case insensitive can you try this

```
form.find('input[name="orderid"]').val(order_id.replace(/sp-/gi, ''));
```

or you can do something like this

```
['SP-', 'sp-', 'eb-', 'EB-'].forEach((item)=>{
   if ( order_id.indexOf(item) !== -1 ) {
        // Remove string from input
        form.find('input[name="orderid"]').val(order_id.replace(item, ''));
    }
});
```

> Update - Just thought of a better solution, find all characters before
> and including - and remove it. So we're not limited to a specific list
> in case new prefixes are added at a later date.
>
> sp-1234, SP-1234, xx-1234, etc.

Maybe something like this should work

```
if(order_id.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
 var prefix = order_id.substr(0, order_id.indexOf('-'));
 form.find('input[name="orderid"]').val(order_id.replace(`${prefix}-`, ""));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the following piece would need to be updated first I suspect, before your line will run: `if ( order_id.indexOf('sp-') !== -1 ) {`

Comment: @wharfdale No, if the string is not found, then nothing will be replaced, so the check isn't necessary.

Comment: @wharfdale I have added a generic approach, plz check if that works

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular expression with case insensitivity set. There is no reason to check for the string exists inside the string because the replace method does not do anything if there is no match.

```js
function removePrefix(str) {
  return str.replace(/(sp|eb)-/i, '');
}


["fo-foooo", "sp-123", "SP-123", "eb-321", "EB-911"].forEach( function (str) {
  console.log(str, removePrefix(str));
});
```

Matching anything that starts with a string followed by a dash

```js
function removePrefix(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[^-]+-/i, '');
}

["fo-foooo", "sp-123", "SP-123", "eb-321", "EB-911"].forEach( function (str) {
  console.log(str, removePrefix(str));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
var vals = ["sp-","ep-"] // Put all the values here

vals.forEach(v => {
  if (order_id.indexOf(v) !== -1) {form.find('input[name="orderid"]').val(order_id.replace(v, ''))};
})
```